# How to parameterize query with special character in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to execute a query with concatenation of two columns so I have done this:

```
Select 
    Id, PtName + ' ('+Investigation+')' as PtName, Y, M, D, PtCode 
From 
    DiagMain
```

But when I am trying to parameterize this query, it's not working.

Like this:

```
declare @Query nvarchar(MAX)

set @Query = 'Select Id, PtName + ''( +''Investigation''+ )'' as PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode FROM DiagMain'
Exec(@Query)
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't Understand What you trying to Parameterized here as your Dynamic Query work as your normal Query.no parameter is assign here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your single quotes were misplaced, they should surround the brackets `(` & `)`:

```
set @Query = 'Select Id, PtName + ''('' +Investigation+ '')'' as PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode FROM DiagMain'
```

You could debug this by using the print command:

```
print @Query
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query ='Select  Id, PtName  + '' (''+Investigation+'')'' as PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode FROM DiagMain'
PRINT @Query
Exec(@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute above query then replace your `Exec(@Query)` with `exec sp_executesql @Query` because to run dynamic query your need to call sql inbuilt procedure. So query you need to run would be following

```
declare @Query nvarchar(MAX)    
set @Query = 'Select Id, PtName + ''( +''Investigation''+ )'' as PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode FROM DiagMain'
exec sp_executesql @Query
```

Happy Coding :-)